# How to parse soap response?

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing

I have wsdl file of webservice. But because of using .net webservice my response include schema and complex type. How should i parse it. Can some wsdlToJava tools creta java class. I ask, Because in wsdl there is no detail about schema that what contains in schema.

Example part of wsdl:

```
 <s:element name="PersonDetailResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PersonDetailResult">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your soap like xml (SAX,StAX,DOM).

Also if you have scheme file you can parse this with help of scheme, if you don't - you have to parse and determine all link to java classes manually.

Comment: With using these, should I parse all my response manually? Or Should I create java class manually. Is there any example link about this stuation.

Comment: I manually parse it with sax, is there any other easier way to do this?

Comment: If you have scheme for this soap - you can do this parse with this scheme (simply use scheme and invoke parse).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/), it has a [wsdl2java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html) tool:

```
wsdl2java -uri ../samples/wsdl/Axis2SampleDocLit.wsdl
```

Comment: How can it know which parameters there are in the class. Because like I said, in wsdl no description about schema details.

Comment: basically a wsdl should contain all the required data needed to produce a client. If the schema is not defined on the wsdl then there is probably a link to a schema and if there isn't then the WSDL is not valid. Anyway, for generating classes from the wsdl, use this tool.